# How to change the xaxis value without chaning the scale in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I have following data

```
data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If I plot it out, the x axis will be 1 - 10.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsWqQ.png)

How can I change the x-axis point 2 become week 0, xaxis point 8 become week 1 without changing the scale.

Using plotly

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSk3t.png)

Just need to change the presentation of the xaxis, but not the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we can convert the x-axis to a string, replace the relevant location with the specified text, and update the x-axis specification.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
new_ticks = [str(x) for x in data]
new_ticks[1], new_ticks[7] = 'week1', 'week2'
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(y=data))

fig.update_xaxes(type='category', ticktext=new_ticks, tickvals=np.arange(1,10))
fig.show()
```

[image]